# Zend Framework select where clause placeholder slows process

Tags: php, zend-framework, placeholder

I'm using Zend Framework 1.12.3, and I've noticed that using the '?' placeholder in the where clause slows down the process:

```
$query = $this->getDbTable()->select()
    ->from($this->getDbTable(), array('id'))
    ->where('id = ?', $id);
```

Is considerably slower than:

```
$query = $this->getDbTable()->select()
    ->from($this->getDbTable(), array('id'))
    ->where('id =' . $id);
```

Here are the getDbTable and setDbTable methods, while $_dbTable is a protected property:

```
public function setDbTable($dbTable)
{
    if (is_string($dbTable)) {
        $dbTable = new $dbTable();
    }
    if (!$dbTable instanceof Zend_Db_Table_Abstract) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid table data gateway provided');
    }
    $this->_dbTable = $dbTable;
    return $this;
}

public function getDbTable()
{
    if (null === $this->_dbTable) {
        $this->setDbTable('V1_Model_DbTable_Users');
    }
    return $this->_dbTable;
}
```

And V1_Model_DbTable_Users class:

```
class V1_Model_DbTable_Users extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'users'; 
}
```

Has anyone encountered the same issue? Do you have any solutions? Thanks

Comment: Could you define "considerably slower"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not consider something slow until you have this behavior. This seems to me an opinion. For the time difference matters, you must be a problem in its architecture levels above that.
Many people spend time trying to find a problem where it does not exist as should improve your own code.

Do not take it so seriously so. It's just something you should consider as constructive.

Comment: I've spent some time researching, it seems that not only the query using the "?" placeholder is slower, but also using the find() method.

I've created a new project based on this quickstart http://www.webpixel.gr/blog/zend-quickstart-tutorial. When calling the find() method inside the viewAction http://test/guestbook/view/id/1, the total load is around 1.10 seconds.

Here's the test project and also the database https://www.dropbox.com/s/tbxf6ycysnr9d9q/test.zip

I don't believe it could be due to my code, since it also happens on a bare project.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I will look at the project.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that your first example is using the feature to quote escape the input, where as the second example is the same as writing it in raw SQL.